# wget truncating url inside docker image

Tags: docker, wget

I am trying to download few pdfs with `wget` inside docker image but it is not working. URLs are getting truncated after **%23** which corresponds to **#** but the command is working perfectly fine outside docker image(I tried on my local machine and few servers).

For example the command `wget 'http://www.scc.virginia.gov/docketsearch/DOCS/3%23yn01!.PDF'` is downloading the correct pdf when run from **outside** of the docker image but when run inside docker image the output is `--2017-05-09 19:18:36--  http://www.scc.virginia.gov/docketsearch/DOCS/3` and results into page not found

wget version is same on my local and inside docker image. I have `RUN apt-get install --yes --force-yes wget` in my dockerfile. Docker version is 1.11.2. What could be the issue?

Comment: Does `docker logs your_container` or `docker events`show interesting things?

Comment: @user2915097 neither `docker logs` nor `docker events` showing anything. never encountered anything like this before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was OS version in base image. I changed `FROM ubuntu:15.10` to `FROM ubuntu:16.04` in docker file and `wget` is working now.